# SenceNet with Azure

Tags: azure

I need some clarification on how to communicate Sense Net 6.0 with Azure Storage location?

If any one know please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you'd configure your application to use a SQL Azure server for its database.  Unless the application has been specifically written to utilize Azure Storage, its not going to work without a lot of porting.